# QGIS Print Composer producing angled graticule lines that look like rectangles instead of squares?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, grids-graticules

I just tried to create an extremely simple map made of one layer loaded as WMS layer from Croatia's geoportal (http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms). I successfully loaded the necessary layer and created everything in Print Composer but I have a problem with the graticule - the grid lines are angled and look like rectangles instead of squares?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The root problem is that a square on the (curved) surface of the earth is not necessarily square when projected flat to a map. The amount of distortion depends on what projection you're using and where in the world you are. The farther away from the equator you are, the greater the difference in meters of what one degree of latitude vs one degree of longitude is. The angle is related to this and what 'north' means.

Answer (score 2):

The CRS layer that you loaded in QGIS is WGS84 (geographic system) and you are setting a grid interval in meters, try to enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation and setting a proper projected CRS (i.e EPSG:32633). Take a look at Project properties dialog to do it:

[image]